# Where does Inbox (by Gmail) store downloaded attachments?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail, file-management

I'm receiving email with attachments on [Google Inbox](https://www.google.com/inbox/). While online, I could open the attachments. Later I would be offline and would like to access those attachments.

So, anyone knows the path where those attachments were downloaded into?

(NB: I'm rooted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the following location to view the attachments:

`(root)/data/data/com.google.android.apps.inbox/files/downloads`

In this location you'll see a random code something like `cd8ca9801230132321232sd312312ad312`

Navigate to that folder and you would see few other folders named

- attachments
- avatars
- smart_hero_mail_image
- smart_mail_image

To view the attachments, navigate to "attachments" folder. Here you'll find lot of folders with random name. Sort the folders based on date, so you could file the most recent ones on top/bottom. The attachments will be stored on random folders, based on when (date) you opened the files via Inbox application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @devav2, on my device it was found at `/data/data/com.google.android.apps.inbox/files/downloads/{some hash}/attachments/{more hashes}/<here goes your files>`. Thanks for giving the idea. The only difference is `/data/data/...` rather than just `/data/...`.

Comment: You are right `/data/data` is the correct path

Comment: On my Galaxy S6, `/data` is empty, and `/sdcard/data/data` contains only one Samsung folder. The Inbox folder seems to be `/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.inbox`, but it contains only an empty `cache` folder. Where else might attachments be saved?